# Can I make Swiper display images the same height, responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, slider, swiper.js

I'm trying to make a vertical slider using Swiper.

It wants to look like the images do on this site

https://www.ikbird.com/

But respond a little better to browser size changes.

Its just to contain images like the example. I want each image to be the same height. So, say it takes up 80% of the screen height.

I can achieve that, but not at the same time as scaling by width

I've tried vh and vw units in css. The problem is, I can get it working for width, but then it doesn't work for height, and vice versa.

I've tried using vh and vw, but nothing seems to work both ways.

Here's one version of CSS I tried:

```
        .swiper-container {
            width: auto;
            height: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            background: blue;
        }
        .swiper-container-container {
            margin-top: 5vh;
            height: 90vh;
            background: green;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            height: 100%;

        }
```

With the HTML (for some reason the vh units break if its not got an outer container)

```
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">

                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/placeholder-a.png"></div>
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/placeholder-b.png"></div>
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/placeholder-c.png"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script>
          var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {

            direction: 'vertical',
            centeredSlides: true,
            /*cssMode: true,*/
            mousewheel: true,
            keyboard: true,
            /*freeMode: true,*/
            spaceBetween: 30,

          })
    </script>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to implement this? If its in a different slider or with a different technique that would be fine.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the same aspect ratio for all images? It's hard to understand you Q (Why this is swiper issue and not images issue inside your slider?)

Comment: Hi thanks for response, sorry it is really complicated and difficult to explain. I guess your're right it probably is just an image issue. No the aspect ratio will be different for all images (landscape, portrait etc.). Its just each image needs to always be the same height (say 80% of screen height). But if its a small screen, it will shrink to say 50% or less of screen height. That's where complexity comes in. I think too many variables for a pure CSS solution. I eventually just used JS on screen resize and some math to resize the image.